# Why Cucumber hook methods aren't lowercase?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Cucumber has a few different hook methods like Before, After or AfterStep.

I was wondering - why doesn't these method names follow Ruby's naming conventions to write method names all lowercase?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The `Before`, `After`, `AfterStep`, `World` etc. Ruby hooks are uppercase because the `Given`, `When`, `Then` Ruby hooks are uppercase.
2. The `Given`, `When`, `Then` Ruby hooks are uppercase because the `Given`, `When`, `Then` Gherkin keywords are uppercase.
3. The `Given`, `When`, `Then` Gherkin keywords are uppercase because the Gherkin language is intended to match the standard template for [BDD User Stories](http://DanNorth.Net/introducing-bdd/).

Answer (score 1):

This is merely speculation on my part but I guess the hook methods' names are camel-cased to match `Then`, `When`, and `Given` methods which are used to define steps:

```
Then "I should be served coffee" do
  @machine.dispensed_drink.should == "coffee"
end
```

Step definition methods' names are in turn camel-cased to match the way scenarios look:

```
Scenario: Buy last coffee
  Given there are 1 coffees left in the machine
  And I have deposited 1$
  When I press the coffee button
  Then I should be served a coffee
```